# .NET MVC4 - Return different subset of fields from Model in the same API controller action

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-apicontroller

I have a model and an action in a WebAPI controller

```
public class MyModel 
{
    public ClassA ObjA { get; set; }
    public ClassB ObjB { get; set; }
    public ClassC ObjC { get; set; }
}
```

and the action:

```
[HttpGet]
public MyModel GetMyModel()
{
    MyModel result = someMethod();

    return result;
}
```

where some properties in `result` could be null. I know that I could use `[JsonIgnore]` to ignore property for serialization but I want this to be dynamic and depending on the data from that were returned from `someMethod()`. Is it possible to only return those properties that aren't `null` in JSON in MVC4 .net so that the client won't get something like `"ObjA": null` in the response? Basically I wanted to hide some properties from the client that they don't need care about.

Comment: If you do not care about null what makes it dynamic at the end you still want to skip nulls why not use [JsonIgnore]

Comment: but depending on situation I could have different properties to be `null`. If I use `[JsonIgnore]` attribute wouldn't that force the property not to be included in every request?

Comment: then you want to write custom logic to avoid nulls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the list of properties on your object with the following:

```
PropertyInfo[] properties = result.GetType().GetProperties();
```

You can then iterate through the list of properties, and create a key/value collection which contains only those that are not null.

```
var notNullProperties = new Dictionary<string, object>();
foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties) 
{
    object propertyValue = property.GetValue(result, null);
    if (propertyValue != null) 
    {
        notNullProperties.Add(property.Name, propertyValue);
    }
 }
```

And then return the serialized dictionary.